# Malformated json when inserting a json in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json

I'm inserting a json in localStorage but I'm getting `Unexpected token ~ in JSON at position 3` when I try to parse it.

This is how I'm inserting to localStorage

```
  localStorage.setItem(
    "users",
    `"[\"~#iM\",[\"loading\",false,\"auth\"]]"`
  );
```

But in localStorage I have

```
"["~#iM",["loading",false,"auth"]]"
```

And doing

```
JSON.parse("["~#iM",["loading",false,"auth"]]")
```

doesn't work but doing

```
JSON.parse("[\"~#iM\",[\"loading\",false,\"auth\"]]")
```

does work.

So the `\` are important. How do I keep them in localStorage?

Comment: Your confused by the way the console shows you string values.

Comment: Get rid of the double quotes outside the outer `[]`. You already have backticks to denote it as string

Comment: It is a simple string. Why do you need to use JSON.parse()?

Comment: @JossClassey obviously to use as array in app

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to store and retrieve objects from the localStorage and as you probably already know, you can only store strings there.

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to convert the object to a string using JSON.stringify:

```
const someKey = 'whatever';

function saveToLocalStorage(obj) {
localStorage.setItem(someKey, JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function retrieveFromLocalStorage() {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(someKey));
}


let someArrayOrObjectToBeStored = [
  "~#iM",
  [
    "loading",
    false,
    "auth"
  ]
];

saveToLocalStorage(someArrayOrObjectToBeStored);

let retrievedObject = retrieveFromLocalStorage();
console.log(retrievedObject)
```

PS: Your edited example doesn't work as you have it quoted twice. Remove the outer backticks to make it work like this:

```
  localStorage.setItem(
    "users",
    "[\"~#iM\",[\"loading\",false,\"auth\"]]"
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the extra quotes or the backticks wrapping the outer `[]`

```
  localStorage.setItem(
    "users",
    `[\"~#iM\",[\"loading\",false,\"auth\"]]`
  );

  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( "users")))
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8s7o12kw/)

Comment: it works but we shouldn't escape with \ when using backquotes, the whole purpose of using other String delimiting quotes is that we don't need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
  localStorage.setItem(
    "users",
    `["~#iM",["loading",false,"auth"]]`
  );

  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")))
```

This worked for me, without the backward slashes.